# How to take emulator screenshots using Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, screenshot, eclipse-3.5

I need to take screenshots of an android application running on an emulator in Eclipse Galileo.

Is there a built-in feature for this or do I have to download a plugin of some sorts?

Comment: Here's an easy screenshot showing how - http://goo.gl/3iO8w

Answer (score 292, accepted):

You can take a screenshot if you open the Android view "devices" (under Window --> Show View --> Other... --> Android --> Devices).  Click on the device or emulator you want to take a screen shot of, then click the "Screen Capture" button (it looks like a little picture, and it should be next to a stop sign button).  Occasionally the device won't immediately load the picture; sometimes you have to close/reopen the screen capture window.

This is equivalent to taking a picture via DDMS, but you can do it in Eclipse instead of opening another application.

Comment: this is excellent. 'emulator control' + 'devices' rids me the need for ddms altogether

Comment: Why is such an essential feature hidden away in these obscure menus? Thanks, man.

Comment: Getting a blank screen when I take screen shot

Comment: @Crocode Make sure to uncheck 'Use Host GPU' for the AVD you are debugging in the Android Virtual Device Manager. I think this is a known bug.

Comment: @Dennis: if I uncheck 'Use Host GPU', I can't be able to launch emulator, it just showing black screen but does not start. do you have any idea on that ?

Comment: @dakshbhatt21 It might be a bug with high res targets and/or scaling when 'Use Host GPU' is off. I couldn't start a Nexus 10 with `-scale .75`, but I could start a 10.1" WXGA with no scaling.

Answer (score 152):

**Screenshots on Android Devices using Eclipse, a Visual Guide**

[image: Android Eclipse Screenshot step 1]

[image: Android Eclipse Screenshot step 2]

[image: Android Eclipse Screenshot step 3]

Comment: Great, thanks. Note that there's no need to use the `Other...` submenu and dialog, as `Devices` is also the 4th item from the top in the `Show View` submenu.

Comment: i wish if i can put +100 for u !

Comment: it should be the accepted answer because of the screenshot

Answer (score 14):

In the DDMS perspective in Eclipse there is a "Screen Capture" button.  (Make sure you have your Android SDK and Eclipse plugin up to date, not sure this was always an option).  Just press that button and a screenshot of whatever device you have DDMS connected to (either a real Android device or the emulator) will be created and opened in a new window where you can save it as a png.

Answer (score 9):

You load the emulator with your app normally, through Eclipse, but you take the actual screenshot from DDMS, a tool that's included in your SDK, under the "tools" folder.

In DDMS, press Ctrl+S to take a screenshot.

Comment: Great!  The standalone DDMS is deprecated now.  Any idea how to use Android Device Monitor?

Answer (score 4):

1-open the DDMS prescriptive,the right click on mouse.
2-there click on export screenshot.
3-then it will show you option to save your file as .png file,with whatever name you like you may save it.

Answer (score 0):

I just do a control print screen, which copies the image into the clipboard, then open MS Paint then do a control Z.  Then you can crop and size it to your liking.  Is this ok?

Comment: this is a long process and tends to be inefficient. it would be easier for you if you could try one of the above methods.

Comment: For some reason the normal capture through DDMS does not work even if the device is visible and LogCat working. The method is a last resort then.