# Screenshot For Device

Tags: android, eclipse, screenshot

I've connecting my device to PC. I would like to take screen shots from my device. How can i done this? I'm using Eclipse IDE. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I don't understand, are you trying to take a screenshot from your Android phone, or do you want to program your app to take a screenshot of your Android device screen ?

Comment: Another answer from a previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065993/how-to-take-emulator-screen-shots-using-eclipse/2066183#2066183

Comment: @Ashish : I want to take screenshot from my Android Phone to my PC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.connect your device to your pc.

2.Open the DDMS

3.select the device from devices options

4. click on srceencapture icon.

see the bellow image.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Start the DDMS perspective from the `Window` menu. On the left side of the window you can see The emulators and devices listed. Select the desired device and click the screen shot option present in same window.

In the image the `Devices` window has the snapshot option enabled.

[image]