# taking android emulator screen shots faster.

Tags: android, screenshot

I have already seen [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065993/how-to-take-emulator-screen-shots-using-eclipse) to find some solution, but couldn't. The given link is able to take the screen shots which are static (I mean the screen which can stay stable for more time).

But my requirement is to take the screen shots of those screens which are not stable for more time. For example: i want to take the screen shot along with the **toast message** on the screen and also i want to take the screen shot of a **camera surface view**.

Is there any way to take screen shots fastly, because while clicking **Capture Screen** button, the **toase message** is being disappeared.

Any help appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is no way you can speed up the process of taking a screenshot from DDMS. Since I am guessing, you want to capture a Toast message, the best possible solution is to set a longer ***length*** for the Toast Message using something like this:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "your message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

And if you do not want a Toast Message to be displayed longer in the final release, you can re-set the ***length*** back to `Toast.LENGTH_SHORT` after you are done taking the screenshot.

Comment: Hmmmm... No known method of speeding up the speed of screenshots that I know of. Then the best possible alternatives are either timing the shot precisely. Or record the screen using an app such as this one: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ms.screencastfree#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDIxMiwiY29tLm1zLnNjcmVlbmNhc3RmcmVlIl0. and then grabbing the frames to your satisfaction.

Comment: The downside is, most of these applications need a rooted device.

Comment: Is there any way that as we run our application it will automatically take each screens until we stop it?

Comment: actually I don't have any device so that app cannot be installed.

Comment: A quick search on Google Play suggests that most apps need a rooted device. The lack of a physical device might be a stumbling block in this exercise.

Answer (score 0):

You could try triggering a screenshot by using a [monkeyrunner](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/monkeyrunner_concepts.html)

Comment: A monkeyrunner would "automatically" take screenshots