# Capture screen showing lines

Tags: android

When I run ddms.bat inside tools directory of android sdk and press Screen Capture I get this

[image]

I tried many tools and utils, but all gets same motion lines. I'm using android 2.3.5 on xperia x10.

Comment: If you're using Eclipse. Then try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2066183/940096) Have a look at [this](http://chicagoandroid.com/profiles/blogs/android-screen-capture-in) also

Comment: Unplug your device. Try to restart your eclipse and reconnect it. And, try it on

Comment: I did everything, I restarted both device and PC twice. Same thing.

Comment: Are you pressing `Ctrl + S` after opening `ddms.bat` file. Try in different PC.

Comment: Your device is incompatible with DDMS' screenshot capability, it appears.

Comment: So, is there any way to make it compatible ?