# Any keyboard shortcut to trigger DDMS screen capture

Tags: android, android-emulator

Most of the time, when I want to capture screen shot of a debugging app, I will use the following button in DDMS.

[image]

However, I was wondering, is there any quick keyboard shortcut to do so, instead of using mouse? This is because in certain situation, I need a screen shot, where the app's UI component is being pressed. I already use up my only mouse to perform the **pressed** action. Hence, there isn't 2nd mouse for me to press the DDMS capture screen button. :)

I do not want to use Windows OS screen capture function. This is because I need an exact color code used in the app sometimes. Using Windows screen capture will not produce accurate image to represent the color used in the app.

Answer (score 0):

[How to take emulator screenshots using Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065993/how-to-take-emulator-screenshots-using-eclipse)

> In DDMS, press Ctrl+S to take a screenshot.