# Create screenshot of a Android 5.0 App with elevation

Tags: android, adb, android-5.0-lollipop, robotium

When i take a screenshot of my app (Material Design with Elevations), the shadow (elevation) is not in the saved screenshot-file.
I try it with a real Device (Nexus 5) and with the google emulator. The screenshots looks fine but the shadows are not included.

i captured the screenshots with solo AND screencap (adb shell).

anybody a idea? thank you

EDIT: Manifest (Part):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="my.package.name"
    android:installLocation="auto"
    android:versionCode="123"
    android:versionName="1.23" >

    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true"
                      android:largeScreens="true"
                      android:normalScreens="true"
                      android:resizeable="true"
                      android:smallScreens="true"
                      android:xlargeScreens="true"/>

    <uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

    <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <!-- ... -->

    <application
    android:name="MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:vmSafeMode="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <!-- definition of receivers -->
    <!-- definition of activities -->
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: I am having no problems capturing screenshots with shadows from system apps on a Nexus 4 (Calculator, Contacts, Play Store) -- I just tested it with the Android Device Monitor. Do you have a reproducible test case for this?

Comment: I second @CommonsWare, no problems with screenshots on Nexus 5; shadows are included.

Comment: ok, it works with a nexus 5 and the android device monitor, but not with a avd device (host gpu enabled).

Comment: can you just show me manifest min and max sdk version?

Comment: @silly: you should update your question by mentioning that it works in nexus5 and avd but doesn't work with host gpu avd.

Answer (score 1):

change in manifest file:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="21"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
```

And now check your code plz.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but the screenshots (taken with solo robotium) are the same (without shadows)

Answer (score 0):

Robotium can take screenshots which include only parts of tested application. It means that for instance status bar is excluded. As far as I know screencap can handle that, but I'm not sure. You can also try another ways of taking screenshots:

1. [using DDMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065993/how-to-take-emulator-screenshots-using-eclipse)
2. [using UIAutomator](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/uiautomator/UiDevice.html#takeScreenshot(java.io.File))
3. [using Android Screenshot Library](https://code.google.com/p/android-screenshot-library/)

Comment: thank you for your answer, the elevation is a part of MY application. The Problem is, the elevation (Shadows) not included in the screenshot.

Comment: Yes, they are part of your application but probably drawn in a different window that is not part of your application. And robotium and such tools, can't access those different windows.